# Absolute moments Inequalities

Tags: probability, expectation, lp-spaces

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ such that $E[|X|^p] < \infty$.
Then via Jensen's inequality we know that  for any $1 \le q \le p$
\begin{align}
E[ |X|^q ] \le  E[ |X|^p ]^{\frac{q}{p}}
\end{align}
Which means that all lower moments a finite as well.

My question is suppose we know what  $E[ |X|^q ]$ and  $E[ |X|^p ]$ are can we have bound on E[ |X|^r ] for $q \le r \le p$ in terms $E[ |X|^q ]$ and  $E[ |X|^p ]$?

Of course we can do what we did before and have $E[ |X|^r ] \le  E[ |X|^p ]^{\frac{r}{p}}$ but this bound does not use knowledge of $E[ |X|^q ]$. Intuition suggest that using  $E[ |X|^q ]$ should improve the bound.

Comment: $E[|X|^q]$ will be useful in obtaining a lower bound for $E[|X|^r]$, so it it improves the knowledge about $E[|X|^r]$ in that sense.

Comment: So, $E[|X|^q]$ carries no information on how large $E[|X|^r]$ can be, only how small?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Liapunov's Inequality for $L_p$ spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235173/liapunovs-inequality-for-l-p-spaces)