# Inclusion in $L^p$ spaces ( Proof check )

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

I am trying to prove, the following question

$ 1\leq p <r <q< \infty $ . Prove that $L^p \cap L^q \subseteq L^r $

The prove that I have written for this is rather straightforward,

basically

$$
|f|^p < |f|^r < |f|^q ,
$$
which implies that

$$
\int |f|^pdu < \int |f|^rdu < \int|f|^qdu
$$

My question is that when moving to the integral sign in step two do I need to invoke any integration theorem such as Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem , or Lebesgue Increasing Convergence theorem ?

If so , then why and how ?

Edit:
I just realised that this proof is wrong as obviously my first inequality doesn't hold for cases where $f<1$

So now I am thinking of proving this with holder's inequality

Comment: It's not true that $||f||_p < ||f||_r < ||f||_q$ so you're trying to prove a false, but stronger statement. You should break $f$ up into $f\chi_{\{|f| > 1\}}$ and $f\chi_{\{|f| \le 1\}}$

Comment: @mathworker21 It is true , Infact I found a proof on the stackexchange. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235173/liapunovs-inequality-for-l-p-spaces

Comment: That's very different from $||f||_p < ||f||_r < ||f||_q$. For an example, take $\frac{1}{x}$ on $[1,2]$.